# group homomorphism from a profinite group continuous iff kernel open

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

I have a question regarding a (probably simple) fact. However I am lacking some basic topological knowledge.

Let $G$ be a locally pro finite group, i.e. ever open neighborhood of $1_G$ contains a compact open subgroup, and $\psi:G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ a group homomorphism. The following are equivalent:

1. $\psi$ is continuous
2. the kernel of $\psi$ is open

So I guess, that 2 $\Rightarrow$ 1: follows from the fact, that if $\psi^{-1}(1)$ is open, since every element of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a scalar multiple of $1$ and the translation is open, $\psi^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ is a open neighborhood of $1$ is a union of open sets and therefore open.

For 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2: I have read, that if $N$ is a open neighborhood to 1 in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, $\psi^{-1}(N)$ is open an contains, since $G$ is locally profinite, a compact open subgroup $K$ of $G$. If $N$ is chosen sufficiently small, it contains no non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^\times$, and so $K\subseteq \ker \psi$.

However, I don't know how $K\subseteq \ker \psi$ implies, that $\ker \psi$ is open.

Thanks in advance for explanations.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $\mathbb{C}^\times$ everywhere ? For your second question, you should try to prove the general fact that a subgroup with nonempty interior is open

Comment: yeah. Alright thanks.

Comment: Hint: if $\psi$ is a continuous homomorphism, then the image of a "small subgroup" of $G$ is a "small subgroup" of $\mathbf{C}$. What can you say of a small subgroup of $\mathbf{C}$?

Answer (score 3):

To show that $K\subseteq \ker \psi$ implies that $\ker \psi$ is open:

---

$K$ is an open subgroup of the subgroup $\ker \psi$. So we can write
$$
\ker\psi = \cup_{g \in \ker\psi} Kg
$$
Which shows that $\ker \psi$ is open.

---

This is generalised in [this](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Etongliu/teaching/598/p-adicrep.pdf) brief note, for any topological group $G$ having  a basis of neighbourhoods of the identity consisting of subgroups (in particular locally profinite groups), and for $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ replaced with any topological group with *no small subgroups* (which includes all Lie groups, so $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$).